# I have a typical two file ASP.NET web page (aspx and aspx.cs) where a message variable is not updated after a Response.OutputStream.Write

Tags: asp.net

I have a message variable I am using to send feedback to the page on submit and on button clicks on errors etc..
It all works fine except any changes to the message variable after I stream a xlsx file out to browser are not updated.

After a Response.OutputStream.Write messages are not updated.

See the comments in the code below.
All other places I update the Msg variable the original html page is updated but not after streaming the xlsx file.
How can a get a message back to the html page after the stream?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" validateRequest="true" CodeFile="file1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Select" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <%=Msg%>
    </body>
</html>

    protected void GetLeads_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Msg ="";
        string scans = GetScans();
            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
            {
            string sql = "SELECT * from table1 where rec in ("+scans+");";
            DataTable dt = loadExternalDataSet(sql);
            
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
                worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

                byte[] bin = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Leads.xlsx\"");
                Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

                Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();  
                
                // This message never displays 
                    Msg = "The file was sent to your browser";          
           
            }
            else
            {
                    
                    // This message displays OK 
                    Msg = "<span style='color:red;'>The barcode scan data is invalid.<br>Try entering it again.</span><br>";    
       
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The message will never display. You can only send one request back to the client. So either an updated html page with the new message OR xlsx file. Not both. Use javascript/ajax to display a message.

Comment: Code after a response.redirect, or response complete will terminate all code - the page is now sent to client - you can't do anything. Try moving your span code above the sending of the response - it "might" work.

Comment: I was “pretty sure” this was the cause 
CompleteRequest()
and there was nothing I could do to work around it.
I just wanted to “be sure” before putting effort into a workaround.

And moving the Msg above CompleteRequest() doesn’t work either.

Thanks for the info everyone.